# Configuring firewall settings for Docker Swarm on Digital Ocean

Tags: linux, docker, digital-ocean

**How can I configure my digital ocean boxes to have the correct firewall settings?**

I've followed the [official guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-cluster-of-docker-containers-with-docker-swarm-and-digitalocean-on-ubuntu-16-04) for getting Digital Ocean and Docker containers working together.

I have 3 docker nodes that I can see when I `docker-machine ls`.  I have created a master docker node and have joined the other docker nodes as workers. However, if I attempt to visit the url of the node, the connection hangs.  This setup is working on local.

Here is my docker-compose that I am using for production.

```
version: "3"

services:
  api:
    image: "api"
    command: rails server -b "0.0.0.0" -e production
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      resources:
        cpus: "0.1"
        memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .env-prod
    networks:
      - apinet
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  client:
    image: "client"
    depends_on:
      - api
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .env-prod
    networks:
      - apinet
      - clientnet
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
      - "35730:35730"
  db:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constaints: [node.role == manager]
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    env_file: .env-prod
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker-volumes/app/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql/data
  redis:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constaints: [node.role == manager]
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker-volumes/app/redis/data:/var/lib/redis/data
  nginx:
    image: app_nginx
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    env_file: .env-prod
    depends_on:
      - client
      - api
    networks:
      - apinet
      - clientnet
    ports:
      - "80:80"
networks:
  apinet:
    driver: overlay
  clientnet:
    driver: overlay
```

I'm pretty confident that the problem is with the firewall settings. I'm not sure however, the ports that need to be open though. I've consulted this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-linux-firewall-for-docker-swarm-on-centos-7).

Comment: Best way to know is, open all the ports and traffic. Check if it works. If it does then it is a firewall issue, if not then it is something else. That gives you a direction

Comment: Ok makes sense.